# Example of quantum entanglement in quantum computing

Tags: entanglement

I am writing an overview of quantum computation for people, who have strong CS and Math backgrounds but don't have experience in this field. I am looking for an elegant example of how entanglement is utilized in quantum computation.

I could've used quantum teleportation as many articles on the internet do, but that is not exactly it. I ended up describing Simon's algorithm in outline, but it is too overloaded with technical details.

Does anybody have advice on how to improve my approach?

Comment: assuming you're sticking to standard (gate-based) schemes of q computation, I don't think the entanglement is that important a property. You obviously need things to be entangled at some point in the circuit, but that's just because for pure states having entanglement is akin to them interacting. The only way to not have entanglement is to have a trivial situation where different qubits do not talk to each other. On the other hand, the presence of entanglement doesn't tell you anything about actual computational usefulness of the circuit.

Comment: Entanglement is already hard to explain to non-physicists (there are plenty of very bad analogies out there), it is even more technical to explain what it does in useful algorithms. However if we stick to quantum gate circuits, there might be some quantum communications protocols ( superdensecoding) that might help, also there might be some small circuit examples in quantum error correction with entanglement if you want to go that path.

Comment: @Mauricio, thank you, I will look up this theme.